# Out of Memory while Traverse Android file system

Tags: java, android

```
public class SDCardFileManager {
public long i = 0;

public void onDirList(){
    try {
        File rootFile = new File("/");
        Log.d("test", "traverse start");
        String json = GsonUtil.list2Json(new SDCardFile(rootFile).list);
        Log.d("test", "traverse finished");
        File file = new File("/sdcard/file.json");
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
        file.createNewFile();
        Log.d("test", "ready to store ");
        OutputStreamWriter oStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "utf-8");
        oStreamWriter.append(json);
        oStreamWriter.close();
        Log.d("test", "json file was stored at "+file.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

class SDCardFile{
    private String filename;
    private boolean isDirectory;
    private String size = "";
    private String date = "";
    public List<SDCardFile> list = new ArrayList<SDCardFileManager.SDCardFile>();

    public SDCardFile(File file) {
        i++;
        this.filename = file.getName();
        this.isDirectory = file.isDirectory();
        if (!isDirectory) {
            size = formatSize(file.length());
            date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(file.lastModified());
        }else{
            File[] DirFiles = file.listFiles();
            if (DirFiles != null) {
                for (final File dirFile : DirFiles) {
                    list.add(new SDCardFile(dirFile));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private String formatSize(long length){
        String size = "";
        if (length<1024) {
            size = String.valueOf(length)+"B";
        }else if (length>=1024&&length<1024*1024) {
            size = String.valueOf(length/1024)+"KB";
        }else if (length>=1024*1024&&length<1024*1024*1024) {
            size = String.valueOf(length/(1024*1024))+"MB";
        }else if (length>=1024*1024*1024) {
            size = String.valueOf(length/(1024*1024*1024))+"GB";
        }
        return size;
    }
}
```

I need to traverse the whole file system and store it as json.I use above code to solve the requirement but while it traverse a big directory, it give me an out of memory crash.Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem? Or is there other way to the requirement?

---

Maybe there was some misunderstand about this question.
I don't need to get the content of the file.I only need its name,create time,size and the directory structure.then store it into a json file ,so other client can analysis it as a file system tree.

Comment: Show the stack trace. How big is that directory?

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the entire file to memory.

When encountering a large file, storing it in memory is not a good idea.

Use a `BufferedWriter` to write the file in chunks, and flush the written content every chunk.

An example of `BufferedWriter` usage if as follows:

```
int chunkSize = someNumber;
int lineCount = 0;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sourceFileName));
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(targetFileName));
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    bw.(writeline);
    lineCount++;
    if(lineCount % chunkSize == 0) {
        bw.flush();
    }
}
bw.close();
br.close();
```

As to the number of lines in chunk, this depends on your system resources. A better approach would be to count the number of characters and not number of lines.